# data not showing in modal from gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, modal-dialog

my data is not showing after clicking the Edit button from the Gridview.

here is my GridView code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID ="panel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="true" OnRowCommand="gv1_RowCommand" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-BackColor="CornflowerBlue" BorderWidth="5" BorderColor="CornflowerBlue" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-hover">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltype" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemType") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Model">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModel" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemModel") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuan" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Unit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUnit" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemUnit") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Target Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemDesc") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Remarks">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRem" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemRemarks") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit">
                <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info" />
                </asp:ButtonField>
            <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStat" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind ("ItemStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID ="ddlStat" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>--%>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is my code for .cs

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //if(e.CommandName.Equals("editRecord"))
        //{

            GridViewRow gvrow = gv1.Rows[index];
            lblIDs.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[0].Text).ToString() ;
            lblitemTypes.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[1].Text).ToString();
            lblModels.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[2].Text).ToString();
            lblQuans.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text).ToString();
            lblUnits.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text).ToString();
            lblDates.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[5].Text).ToString();
            lblDescs.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[6].Text).ToString();
            lblRemarkss.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[7].Text).ToString();
            //ddlStat.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[8].Text).ToString();
            lblResult.Visible = false;
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("$('#editModal').modal('show');");
            sb.Append(@"</script>");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
```

the page goes through but it doesnt show the data from the gridview, i tried to put a breakpoint and i see that it doesnt have anyvalue inside, what is my error? is the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode correct? how can i transfer the data to the modal for editing. thank you!

Comment: try in this way                                                                                               var clickedRow = clickedButton.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
       
   var clickedUserName = clickedRow.Cells[0].Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an `UpdatePanel` warp your code and your code not work after a post back you need to do two thinks to find the issue.

1. Temporary Remove the `UpdatePanel` and repeat what you do and see if the problem is on your code behind.
2. place back the `UpdatePanel` and open the javascript console of your browser and check for javascript errors.